# error in code for colouring of a chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I wanted to use this code

```
Sub PieMarkers()

Dim chtMarker As Chart
Dim chtMain As Chart
Dim intPoint As Integer
Dim rngRow As Range
Dim lngPointIndex As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim myTheme As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set chtMarker = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtMarker").Chart
Set chtMain = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtMain").Chart

Set chtMain = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtMain").Chart
Set rngRow = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("PieChartValues").RefersTo)

For Each rngRow In Range("PieChartValues").Rows
    chtMarker.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngRow
    SetColorScheme chtMarker, x
    chtMarker.Parent.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    lngPointIndex = lngPointIndex + 1
    chtMain.SeriesCollection(1).Points(lngPointIndex).Paste
    x=x+1
    Debug.Print rngColors.address()
Next

lngPointIndex = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


 Sub SetColorScheme(cht As Chart, i As Long)

    Dim y_off As Long, rngColors As Range
    Dim x As Long

    y_off = i Mod 13

    'this is the range of cells which has the colors you want to apply
    Set rngColors = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Basic").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Basic").Range("A19").Value).Offset(y_off, 0)

    With cht.SeriesCollection(1)
        'loop though the points and apply the corresponding fill color from the cell
        For x = 1 To .Points.Count
            .Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                             rngColors.Cells(x).Interior.Color
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

to colour several pie charts with all of them having the same amount of slices (3 each, 8 pie charts) according to specified colours in the workbook (colours used as background colour for a cell in a worksheet).This is the Sub Colour Scheme.

The code compiles without error the problem is just that it only uses the first to specified colours in a range (say A10:Z10, only the colours in A10 and B10 to colour all pieces of the 8 pie charts (24 sclices in total with the two colours from  A10 and B10). Could somebody tell me what I would need to change so that the whole colour range from A10 to X10 is used (24 different colours) for the different slices?

Comment: What is in A19 of the Basic worksheet?

Comment: What is the value of x when you call SetColorScheme?  You haven't initialized it, and you don't increment it in the loop...

Comment: ...and this is now your ninth question on essentially the same problem.

Comment: Tim, I thought I iniialised the variable where I wrote Dim x As Long. I changed the last bit of the loop to x=x+1 but the problem persists. Do you have an idea what might be related to it?

Comment: A19 is a cell in whcih the range is saved ( just entered as in A10:A13 where the background colour of the cells is read from). I updated the code to increment x with 1 after each run but the problem I mentioned above did not change

Comment: Try adding a `Debug.Print rngColors.address()` to check its what you expect.

Comment: I tried to enter your code as I updated teh answer ( in the position in hwich I updated it but I got an error that the object is missing) I created a new question ( this might not be the right way but I woudl really! need a solution) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537341/loop-increment-error I would really really appreciate if you coudl look over it

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `For loop that use cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count` as a boundary doesn't take you beyond two iterations.

You should rather use an inner loop specific to the range of cells you want to retrieve the color from and a if condition statement if there are less colors.

Comment: coudl you possibly elaborate a bit and could provide an exampele in th ecode I posted?